# How to remove/delete Shared item in Rhythmbox - DAAP share

Tags: rhythmbox, daap

I somehow added a Share in Rhythmbox 3.3.

Running on Ubuntu 16.04

[image]

**#1**
I cannot find how to remove the Share

**#2**
I get a permanent status/progress message:
"Retrieving songs from music share"

I've searched all over and cannot find any clues.

From what I understand, this is a DAAP share, and it is not stored directly in the Rhythmbox configuration files.

I have found this:

**How do I remove a DAAP Share from Rhythmbox? Ubuntu 9.10**
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1407496

The advice is to restart Rhythmbox.
I have done that several times.
The entry remains.

I also found this:

**[Rhythmbox-devel] How do I remove an entry from the DAAP "Shared" list?**
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/rhythmbox-devel/2010-February/msg00020.html

The same advice is to restart Rhythmbox.

> Rhythmbox doesn't store manually added DAAP shares anywhere. Just
>   restarting it is enough to get rid of them. It sounds like you've
>   tried that, though, so maybe there's something else going on. How
>   exactly did you add these non-working entries?

Again, I have done that several times.
Again, the entry remains.

I have searched all the Rhythmbox config files ... no luck.

I have searched for DAAP config files ... no luck either.

**How do I remove the shares ?**

Any suggestions are welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution.

[image]

From Rhythmbox **Top Menu**:

- **[ Tools ]**

  - **[ Plug-ins ... ]**

In the **Configure Plug-ins** window:

- Select:

  - **[x] DAAP Music Sharing**
- Click:

  - **[ Preferences ]**

In the **DAAP Music Sharing** pop-up:

- Click:

  - **[ Forget known remotes ]**
  - **[ Close ]**

That makes the share disappear.

I closed Rhythmbox - just to make sure that the config was saved.

And restarted.

Finally - after 3 months of annoyance - no more share !!!

**[EDIT-UPDATE] Fuller Answer - More Info**

While I was trying to sort this out, I had the following running in a terminal window:

`avahi-browse -a`

When I went to close down my "diagnostic" terminal I saw:

`+ wlp2s0 IPv4 Hlaka Mamabolo___s Library     iTunes Audio Access  local`
`+ wlp2s0 IPv6 Hlaka Mamabolo___s Library     iTunes Audio Access  local`

So this turns out to be a guy in my digs, running his Apple on the same Wifi network.

When:

- **DAAP Music Sharing** is enabled
- Rhythmbox seems to be auto-discovering local DAAP servers

So:

- although the **[ Forget known remotes ]** removed the share
- the auto-discover put it back a few minutes later

So my full solution was to:

- **[ Forget known remotes ]**
- and then disable the Plug-in
- **DAAP Music Sharing**

Not an ideal solution for *everyone* - but seeing as I am not interested in using DAAP anywhere, it solves my own annoying issue.

Perhaps the "diagnosis info" above will be helpful to someone else.